# Stream API - сортировка map

Tags: java, api, steam

Случился затык. На вход подается текст, нужно подсчитать количество повторяющихся слов и вывести их в порядке от наиболее повторяющихся к наименее повторяющимся, затык в следующем. Как их можно отсортировать не только по количеству повторений, но и в лексикографическом порядке. (т.е. если есть два слова повторяющихся одинаковое число раз, отсортировать их в лексикографическом порядке).. Уже всю голову сломал .. Пока у меня получилось отсортировать только по количеству повторений..

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader inputLines = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, charset));
String wordsInText = inputLines.readLine();
Stream.of(wordsInText.split("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+"))
        .map(String::toLowerCase).forEach(p -> list.add(p));
Map<String, Long> countWords = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
countWords.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
public static List<String> getRepeatedWordsSorted(String str) {
    Enumeration<String> st = (Enumeration<String>)(Enumeration) new StringTokenizer(str);

    Map<String, Integer> countMap = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(st.asIterator(), 0), false)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(v -> v, v -> 1, Integer::sum));

    Map<Integer, Stream<String>> reverseCountMap = countMap.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, e -> Stream.of(e.getKey()), Stream::concat));

    return reverseCountMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .map(e -> e.getValue().sorted()).flatMap(v -> v).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Хотя соседний вариант с компаратором всё же лучше и с ним этот метод был бы таким:

```
public static List<String> getRepeatedWordsSorted(String str) {
    Enumeration<String> st = (Enumeration<String>)(Enumeration) new StringTokenizer(str);

    Map<String, Integer> countMap = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(st.asIterator(), 0), false)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(v -> v, v -> 1, Integer::sum));

    return countMap.entrySet().stream().sorted((es1, es2) ->
            es1.getValue().equals(es2.getValue()) ?
                    es1.getKey().compareTo(es2.getKey()) :
                    es1.getValue().compareTo(es2.getValue()))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Передаем свою лямбду как компаратор (меняется только последняя строка вашего кода):

```
countWords.entrySet().stream().sorted((item1, item2) ->
        !item1.getValue().equals(item2.getValue()) ?  // Если значения не одинаковы...
                -item1.getValue().compareTo(item2.getValue()) : // то сравниваем по значениям (минус для обратного порядка)
                item1.getKey().compareTo(item2.getKey()))  // если одинаковы - то сравниваем ключи
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Возможно будет понятнее, если расписать через `if`:

```
countWords.entrySet().stream().sorted((item1, item2) -> {
    if (!item1.getValue().equals(item2.getValue())) { // если значения не одинаковы...
        return -item1.getValue().compareTo(item2.getValue()); // то сравниваем по значениям
    } else {
        return item1.getKey().compareTo(item2.getKey());  // если одинаковы - то по ключам
    }
}).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Лучше немного переставить операторы, чтобы избавиться от `!` и `-`.

Comment: `!` - в данном случае подчеркивается, что сначала сравнение идет по значениям, а потом по ключам. Минус можно убрать перестановкой `item1` и `item2` местами, но это не так хорошо заметно, как торчащий в начале строки минус.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста ресурс где можно про это подробнее почитать. Очень тяжело если честно для восприятия. Почему именно так ...

Comment: @Васька, что именно "почему именно так"? Про компаратор можно тут почитать например: [Comparator в Java](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1939-comparator-v-java)

Comment: да меня не тернарный оператор испугал =) А сама конструкция в целом. Я даже если честно немного теряюсь как сформулировать. Но в целом по коду понятно... 

Спасибо!

Пойду почитаю теорию, в том числе и по sorted ....

Comment: @insolortiredofthisdrama я тут придумал вот такое решение еще

countWords.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey)).sorted(Comparator.comparing((Map.Entry<String, Long> entry) -> entry.getValue()).reversed());

Comment: @Васька, в этом варианте вторая сортировка полностью перекроет предыдущую сортировку (как будто вы первый раз и не сортировали)

Comment: @insolortiredofthisdrama, а почему у меня не перекрывает и правильно все выводит? 

.sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByKey())
                .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
                .limit(10)
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: @Васька, https://ideone.com/tE3WhZ

Comment: Если бы правильно сортировало (как вам нужно), то после второй сортировки ничего бы не изменилось, а так вторая сортировка просто игнорирует результат первой сортировки.

Comment: @insolortiredofthisdrama

        i.lines().map(line -> line.toLowerCase().split("[^\\p{L}\\p{Digit}_]+"))
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Map.Entry<String, Long> entry) -> entry.getValue()).reversed())
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .limit(10)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        i.close();

Comment: Я извиняюсь за жуткий неформат кода =(

Comment: @Васька с группировкой можно, но с тем кодом что в ответе проще.

Answer (score 0):

запускаю 2 стрима, что не есть хорошо, но рефакторинг уже на вашей совести. на быструю руку примерно так:

```
BufferedReader inputLines = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, charset));
String wordsInText = inputLines.readLine();
Map<String, Long> result = Stream.of(wordsInText.split("[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+"))
        .map(String::toLowerCase)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((e1, e2) -> {
            final int compareResult = e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
            return compareResult != 0 ? compareResult : e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey());
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (x, y) -> y, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> sortedList = Stream.of("13","13","23", "12", "12", "23")
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))//считаем элементы
                .entrySet()//достаем пары слово-количество
                .stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))//сначала сортируем по количеству, если равны, то по значению (тут .reversed())
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)//достаем значения
                .collect(Collectors.toList());//собираем
```

Реезультат [12, 13, 23]

Если есть желание отсортировать в порядке убывания, то можно использовать .reversed()